# Как создать для каждого клиента свой поток, чтобы не было ошибки thread creation error

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

Клиент  - это бесконечный цикл  существует на протяжении всей жизни программы ему требуется отдельный поток.

Если клиентов много, то ресурсов системы не хватает чтобы создать нужное кол-во отдельных потоков

Как сделать 1 поток для 2х и более клиентов?

Можно ли это сделать через ITask если да то как?

Возможное решение, как я думаю, это некий менеджер потоков, который не будет создавать для каждого клиента свой поток,
а как-то использовать один поток для нескольких клиентов.
Как это сделать тоже не знаю.

Так как в клиенте есть sleep продолжительный и пока он выполнится можно же другой клиент выполнить но как переключится на другой клиент, ведь все тогда сведется к рекурсии и переполнению стека.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
type
  TClient2 = class
    id: Integer;
    I: Integer;
    procedure Run;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TClient2.Run;
begin
  I:=0;
  while true do
  begin
    Inc(I);
    TThread.Sleep(1000);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Cl: TClient2;
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to 2000 do
  begin
    Cl := TClient2.Create;
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(Cl.Run).Start;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Архитектура выглядит неправильной - у вас 2000 клиентов и под каждого свой поток который 99% времени проводит во сне?

Comment: @Kromster Это не реальный код а пример, который показывает что не получится у меня запустить очень много потоков. А они нужны или другая альтернатива. Что вы имеете ввиду "Архитектура " = (говно код который ничего не делает). Ну а как вам пример показать. в реальной проге пустого sleep будет а будет своя логика.

Comment: Если у вас 2000 клиентов и каждый постоянно что-то делает - вам никакого сервера не хватит это обеспечить вычислительными мощностями. Выполнить больше "работы", чем у вас физически доступно ядер процессора * 2 - не получится. Число потоков у вас должно быть боле-менее равно числу ядер * 2. Все остальные потоки будут просто стоять.

Comment: То есть смотрите, в любом случае неправильно плодить столько потоков. Вам надо реорганизовать архитектуру, чтобы потоков было меньше, и загружать их работой по мере её поступления.

Comment: https://www.transl-gunsmoker.ru/2010/09/windows-2000.html

Comment: @Kromster
если в потоке есть sleep то процессор не будет его ждать а будет выполнять др поток  а стек вызовов сохранится в том потоке. таким образом в теории хоть миллиарды потоком могут быть в системе а по факту работать будет только 10 если 10 ядер. поэтому мои запросы не из другой галактики.

Comment: @Kromster
Скорее всего буду разбивать объект клиента на части. и быстрые операции проверки объединять в один поток а долгие cо слипом в отдельные.

Comment: @Vlad Chapl вот есть вопрос если конечно знаете. на сайте затрагивается тема  объект -  поток          . Если объект в куче находится и этот объект в потоке выполняется расходуется ли стек потока на этот объект или нет? я думаю да. но не уверен. стек это не куча. кто знает? При условии что объект был создан не в потоке а в потоке только ссылка на него

Comment: Тело объекта лежит в куче. Сама переменная объекта - указатель (4/8 байт) может храниться в куче, в стеке главного потока, или в стеке дополнительного потока, в зависимости от того, где она объявлена (но при таких размерах, думаю, место хранения пофиг)

Comment: @MBo
 в вопросе размер класса это только пример. реальный размер достаточно большой с кучей полей. Поэтому и спросил будет ли стек потока тратится на этот объект который был создан в другом потоке. А можно ли это как то проверить запустив рекурсию не в потоке на в объекте при условии что вход в объект был с потока

Comment: Вы осознали, что сами данные объекта всегда будут в куче? В стеке потока будут храниться локальные переменные поточной функции (Execute для обычного TThread или указанная в аргументе CreateAnonymousThread) и локальные переменные функций, вызванных из этой самой поточной функции без синхронайзов.

Comment: @MBo
Понял Спасибо